# Can't work out why array updating when it shouldn't be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, debugging, canvas

I'm building Conway's game of life with Javascript and HTML5 Canvas. 
The code here is within the context of a gameOfLife object:

```
this.cells = [];
this.nextCellState = [];
```

After populating `this.cells` with my cell objects, I populate `this.nextCellState` like so:

```
this.nextCellState = this.nextCellState.concat(this.cells);
```

On mouse click, the corresponding cell object property isAlive is turned true:

```
function clickAlive(x, y) {
    for (var i in this.cells) {
        if (x.between(this.cells[i].x, this.cells[i].x + cellsize) && y.between(this.cells[i].y, this.cells[i].y + cellsize)) {
            this.cells[i].isAlive = true;
            console.log('Breakpoint');
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, having a look at `cells` and `nextCellState` arrays at the breakpoint, both of them have the clicked cell activated to `true`.

What is causing this?

Comment: Don't use a `for in` loop to iterate an array. Use a normal `for` loop. It won't fix your problem, but it's a design suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy the contents of `cells` into `nextCellState`, you are making a shallow copy of the array. The objects themselves are now aliased by the two arrays (that is, `cells[0]` and `nextCellState[0]` refer to the same object).

You need to create new objects in `nextCellState` to be able to change the objects' internal states independently. The easiest would be if your cell objects had a copy constructor function. Then you could do something like this:

```
this.nextCellState = this.nextCellState.concat(
    this.cells.map(function(cell) {
        return cell.copy();  // or whatever your copy constructor is
    })
);
```